# How do I test for a custom class derived from Attribute in a template page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So I created a custom Attribute that I will used to decorate StepViewModels.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class WizardStepAttribute : Attribute
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    //public virtual int? Order { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Email","ConfirmEmail")]
[WizardStep(Name="Preparer's Information")]
public class Step0ViewModel : IStepViewModel
{...
```

In my IStepViewModel.cshtml I want to display the WizardStep property name if it exists.

Here is my own pretend code for what I want to happen...

`@Html.Label(ViewModel.ModelMetaData.Properties("WizardStep").Name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to implement a custom model metadata provider to add metadata to the model based on the attribute:

```
public class MyModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{

    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<System.Attribute> attributes, System.Type containerType, System.Func<object> modelAccessor, System.Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        var wizardStepAttr = attributes.OfType<WizardStepAttribute >().FirstOrDefault();
        if (wizardStepAttr != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("WizardStep", wizardStepAttr);
        }
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

... then pull that data from the model metadata:

```
@Html.Label(((WizardStepAttribute)ViewModel.ModelMetaData.AdditionalValues["WizardStep"]).Name)
```

You will have to register this metadata provider in `Application_Start` like so:

```
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyModelMetadataProvider();
```

(Note that some DI Framework extensions for MVC automatically wire this up if you bind `ModelMetadataProvider` to `MyModelMetadataProvider`)

Comment: What do I return from that CreateMetaData method?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain: Sorry, I got interrupted. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great answer.  I'm having one problem.  in the `attributes` Ienumerable collection of <System.Attribute>  there isn't any item of type WizardStepAttribute, so the if condition never gets executed.  How do I wire up the WizardStepAttribute item to get included in the attributes variable?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain: It should be put there by virtue of your putting the `WizardStepAttribute` on the class for the model in question. Make sure `CreateMetadata` is being run on the model object that you think it's being run on.